# Targeting specific PHP tag with regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

All my wordpress websites have recently been hacked, and a very long PHP line has been added on top of all PHP files.

It looks like that (juste a sample of the entire code)

```
<?php $gqmtlkp = '~ x24<!%o:!>! x242178}527}88:}35csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]y]252]18y]#>q%
```

The problem is that code is generated and is different in all files. But I noticed that every code contains

```
explode(chr((729-609))
```

Can someone help me with building a regex line, that will target first **php tag** (optional) **containing** : (numbers vary)

```
explode(chr((xxx-xxx))
```

so that I can automatically remove it in every files ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Removing this code is highly unlikely to remove the hack. Better to wipe and reinstall from backup. Also, change all your credentials (db, ftp, ssh, cpanel) and update all your software.

Comment: Do not try to do it yourself. Please check this: http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/ and this: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will try that out, even if I already tested a lot  of things. But anyway, I will need to clean all websites and files after I managed to stop the hackers. Can someone help me with a regex ?

Comment: @Neoweiter were you able to figure out regex solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your request you're looking to escape the following format: `<?php(optional) explode(chr((xxx-xxx)))` <- your sample was missing a third closing paranthesis for explode() function so I added it. If that's not right then just remove the last `\)` portion.

Try this: `/(\<\?php)? explode\(chr\(\([0-9]{3,3}-[0-9]{3,3}\)\)\)/`

Not sure if space after optional first php tag is necessary. You can adjust it going from there.